# Should we edit questions in answers when reviewing?

Tags: discussion

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/491512/156344) is a question.

Not surprisingly, it was taken to the Low Quality Posts review queue. Of course, it is a question not an answer, so it deserves deletion.

However, [the review](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/171375) ended with an "Edit" revision. It makes the review complete, thus the answer is not deleted.

I know the intention of Pinnow is good: the post needs improvements in formatting. However, by doing so, he accidentally pressed the decisive "Keep undeleted" button, which is not appropriate in this case.

So what I ask here is

> Should we even improve formatting for posts which are going to be deleted?

Note that when you edit a post by the review queue, the review becomes completed right after that. So in my opinion, we can edit posts if necessary, but *not in the review queue*, except you intentionally want to keep that post. And, I am sure Pinnow wants to delete the post rather than keeping it.

Note that I flagged the answer after knowing that the review had completed. But <strike>it seems to me that</strike> [there will be no new review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321056/410270), so we should really avoid situations like this.

---

**Edit:** The answer is now deleted by a moderator, but I am looking forward for a general answer.

Comment: I've just flagged it as "not an answer" please let me know if you see it in the "low quality" queue now.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thanks, but as you read in the link, now it only goes to the moderator queue. It will never go to the Low Quality Posts queue again

Comment: Hence, the answer is simply "no" :)